# How to add a class to the first child in foreach in Umbraco

Tags: html, foreach, umbraco

I am making a dynamic Bootstrap column in Umbraco. How can I assign class "`col-md-offset-1`" only to the first child in the column `col-md-2`?

```
@{
   foreach (IPublishedContent list in homeList.Where(x => x.IsVisible()))
   {
      string text = list.GetPropertyValue<string>("listText");
      string style = list.GetPropertyValue<string>("listItemStyle");

      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
         <div class="circle"><i class="@style"></i></div>
            <p>@text</p>
      </div>
   }
 }
```

Comment: On every single first child of `cold-md-2 text-center` div? If you can give a final html structure I can help you. What do you want the outcome to be like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something along the lines of:

```
@{
   var additionalClassForFirstItem = "col-md-offset-1";
   foreach (IPublishedContent list in homeList.Where(x => x.IsVisible()))
   {
      string text = list.GetPropertyValue<string>("listText");
      string style = list.GetPropertyValue<string>("listItemStyle");

      <div class="col-md-2 text-center @{additionalClassForFirstItem}">
         <div class="circle"><i class="@style"></i></div>
            <p>@text</p>
      </div>
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(additionalClassForFirstItem)) {
         additionalClassForFirstItem = string.Empty;
      }
   }
 }
```

or iterate `for` using integer variable, like `for (int i = 1, ..)` , and check if it is = 1